# UPload image by using Class object in PHP

Tags: php

I am not getting this code working, was tyring to upload an image using class object, The form is correctly displayed when executed but image is not shown in browser when clicked on submit button, can we use class objects in this way to execute this code.

```
<?php

$obj=new test();
$obj->disp();

class test
{
    var   $name;
    public  $val=5;
    //public $arr=array('1'=>array('a'=>'val 1', 'b'=>'val2'),'2'=>array('c'=>'val 1', 'd'=>'val2'));

    function __construct()
    {

    }

      function disp()
    {
        echo <<<_END
<html><head><title>PHP Form Upload</title></head><body>
<form method='post' action='home1.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10'>
<input type='submit' value='Upload'>
</form>
_END;
if ($_FILES)
{
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
echo "Uploaded image '$name'<br><img src='$name'>";
}


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working very well. There is no issue in this. if you get any error or your image is not shown, then please check that the file name and **action of form** is same.

Comment: the filename is home1.php, which is same as action name, still does not show image on my screen..